# How to set parametres for IDA PRO for decompile Firmware Motorola HC908JB8JDW

Tags: ida, motorola

Hope someone can help me to set parametres for IDA PRO for decompile Firmware Motorola HC908JB8JDW
i tried every combinanated value but without sucess.

[image: Memoy map**strong text**]

[image: ida]

Comment: I don’t know this dialog but at first glance you’re only defining the memory range 0xDC00-0x2DBFF but you’re trying to load your image at offset 0. What is your image - a complete 64K memory dump? You probably need to create a RAM segment too up to DC00. Or just the ROM image? You need to load it at DC00. Your 20000 looks too big, by the way.

Comment: hi  i want to creat a rom image. yes it 64k seiz. yay its 2000; i maked a mistak on tapying